# How can we use itextsharp in mvc3?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

Hello everyone I'm a beginner in MVC3 so I'm trying to use pdf reporting with itextsharp but I'm confused to how to use it. Could you suggest me to how use itext sharp in MVC3 tutorial or example?

Comment: I answered something similar before

[Making a Pdf from a view][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12796940/how-to-make-a-pdf-report-of-a-particular-view-in-mvc3/12798212#12798212

HTH

Si

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd have a look into iTextSharp examples in general, with a slant towards creating one in memory and saving it into a `Stream` rather than a file.  Then look into using an MVC action method return an file stream action result using something like the snippet below at the end of your action method:

```
return File(pdfStream, "application/pdf", "PdfFileName.pdf");
```

Where `pdfStream` would be the stream generated by your iTextSharp PDF document and `PdfFileName.pdf` is the name you want the PDF to be opened/saved as.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, there isn't much MVC specific. You have to make Action which you'll request to generate pdf and return a file, and put all itextsharp magic in this Action:

```
public ActionResult Download()
{
   //MAGIC HERE
   return File(file, "application/pdf", "file.pdf");
}
```