# Generate PDF from view using iTextSharp

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, pdf-generation, itext

My requirement is to have a button in my view and clicking on that should generate a PDF report from that view. (Should avoid making another trip to database to get data for the PDF report).

I decided to use iTextSharp. Could some body please post some examples or direct me to a proper article?

Comment: why down vote? what's wrong with the inquiry?

Answer (score 3):

I answered something similar on this link.

You will need to sort out the caching of the data from the DB though, this version just queried it again.

[How to make a pdf report of a particular view in mvc3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12796940/how-to-make-a-pdf-report-of-a-particular-view-in-mvc3/12798212#12798212)